# Removing all items with duplicates from list

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I have a list that look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
```

And I want to delete all items that have duplicates so I get something like this:

```
[1, 4]
```

Because 2 and 3 have duplicates. I know sets, but they don't achieve what I want. Is there a short and effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short:

```
filtered_list = [x for x in your_list if your_list.count(x) == 1]
```

Effective (for large lists):

```
counters = dict.fromkeys(your_list, 0)
for item in your_list:
    counters[item] += 1
filtered_list = [x for x in your_list if counters[x] == 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
def getUnique(myList):
    cnt = Counter()
    for item in myList:
        cnt[item] += 1
    return [i for i in cnt if cnt[i] < 2]

print getUnique(myList)
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can achieve like this:**

```
 import collections
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2]
    remove = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count > 1]
    print([x for x in a if x not in remove])
```

**output: [1, 4]**